# Firebase Authentication via Cloud Functions using Express

Tags: react-native, express, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions

Im building a mobile App using React Native and CloudFunctions as back-end, which will allow only authenticated users to access the RealTime database. In authentication I would like to send to this function the email and password and then the back-end create the user, and send me back the token which I will use to make the request to api. I would to know if the is it possible and the right approach, or should I authenticate the user first directly by my App and then calls the functions with the token that I got ...

If someone have some exemplo would be awesome.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Typically the client application performs the signin process so it can make use of the authentication token and keep it refreshed.

Comment: Thanks Doug, its more appropriate